# How to create sql procedure for calculating Total dues

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2000, crystal-reports-8.5

Can anyone help me by showing a create procedure statement for calculating Total Dues from three tables? Here are the tables along with their data ..

**Table_1**

```
accountno   shipername   shiperaddress   Executivename
   001      john         123, London          Paul
   002      Robi         127, China           Soma
```

**Table_2**

```
Executivename shipername shiperaddress accountno currentamount anotheramount    
   paul          john     123,london     001         10500       12000
   soma          robi     127,china      002         11000        6800
```

**Table_3**

```
accountno    Date        ReceivedAmount    MoneyReceiptNo
   001       1/1/2012       6500              G 256412
   002       1/2/2012       5200              D 246521
```

Here I am to mention that the Total Dues will be calculated as

```
(currentamount + anotheramount) - receivedamount
```

I tried to do that by the following stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptexetotaldues] @Executivename varchar(20) 
AS BEGIN
    select 
        table_1.Executivename, 
        sum(table_2.currentamount + table_2.anotheramount
             - table_3.receivedamount ) as TotalDues 
    from 
        table_1 
    full join 
        table_2 on table_1.accountno = table_2.accountno 
    join 
        table_3 on table_3.accountno = table_1.accountno 
    where 
        table_1.Executivename = @Executivename 
    group by 
        table_1.Executivename
end
```

But that doesn't work. Please somebody help me.

Comment: It's **shipper** (with two `p`) - and also: what do you need `Table_1` for?? `Table_2` contains all the same information - and more - as are stored in `Table_1`... not a very normalized design ....

Comment: How does it fail?  Is this a syntax problem or a calculation problem?

Comment: This is calculation problem i think.Report only generates Executive name.TotalDues is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Your sample worked for me.  The only thing I changed is "Date" to transdate.  I strongly recommend avoiding "Date" as a column name.  I also changed the aliasing a bit, but that should have been allright.  I thinkg @Gordon Linoff is right - you could have an issue with NULLS.

```
DECLARE @table_1 TABLE (accountno char(5), shipername char(20), shiperaddress char(40), Executivename varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @table_1 VALUES ('001', 'john', '123, London', 'Paul')
INSERT INTO @table_1 VALUES ('002','Robi','127, China','Soma')

DECLARE @table_2 TABLE (Executivename varchar(20), shipername char(20), shiperaddress char(40),
                        accountno char(20), currentamount decimal(10,2), anotheramount decimal(10,2))

INSERT INTO @table_2 VALUES ('paul', 'john','123,london','001',10500, 12000)
INSERT INTO @table_2 VALUES ('soma', 'robi', '127,china', '002', 11000, 6800)

DECLARE @table_3 TABLE(accountno char(20), tranDate datetime, ReceivedAmount decimal(10,2), MoneyReceiptNo char(10))
INSERT INTO @table_3 VALUES ('001', '1/1/2012', 6500, 'G 256412')
INSERT INTO @table_3 VALUES ('002', '1/2/2012', 5200,'D 246521')


DECLARE @Executivename varchar(20) 

--SET @Executivename = 'Paul'
SET @Executivename = 'Soma'

    select 
        tb1.Executivename, 
        sum(tb2.currentamount + tb2.anotheramount - tb3.receivedamount ) as TotalDues 
    from 
        @table_1 tb1
        full join @table_2 tb2 on tb1.accountno = tb2.accountno 
        join @table_3 tb3 on tb3.accountno = tb1.accountno 
    where 
        tb1.Executivename=@Executivename group by tb1.Executivename
```

Here are my results:

```
Executivename   TotalDues
Soma    12600.00
```

Comment: Thanks million for your reply.but if there are more than 1 client of an Executive, will it work perfectly? suppose about another client,whose executivename=soma, accountno=003, shipername=XYZ, shiperaddress=Bangladesh, currentamount=12000, anotheramount=8000, and in the table_3, receivedamount=5000.then soma's TotalDues=?  I m having the problem.The result is not generating correctly.I am not understanding why is this happening???

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two problems.  First is that the account number is duplicated in either table 1 or table 2.  This will add extra rows.

The second is that there are rows in table three that are not in table 2.  This means that the addition within the sum is NULL because one of the values is NULL.  You can fix this in one of these ways:

```
    sum(table_2.currentamount) + sum(table_2.anotheramount) - sum(table_3.receivedamount)
```

or

```
    sum(coalesce(table_2.currentamount, 0.0) + coalesce(table_2.anotheramount, 0.0) - coalesce(table_3.receivedamount, 0.0) ) as TotalDues
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more straightforward as a UNION query, example below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptexetotaldues] @Executivename varchar(20) 
AS BEGIN

SELECT SUB.ACCOUNTNO, SUM(SUB.DUE) AS TOTALDUE FROM 
  (SELECT ACCOUNTNO
        , CURRENTAMOUNT AS DUE
   FROM TABLE_2
   INNER JOIN TABLE_1 -- WILL ONLY WORK IF ACCOUNTNO IS UNIQUE WITHIN TABLE_1
   ON TABLE_1.ACCOUNTNO = TABLE2.ACCOUNTNO
   WHERE TABLE_1.EXECUTIVENAME = @Executivename

   UNION ALL

   SELECT ACCOUNTNO
        , ANOTHERAMOUNT AS DUE
   FROM TABLE_2
   INNER JOIN TABLE_1 
   ON TABLE_1.ACCOUNTNO = TABLE2.ACCOUNTNO
   WHERE TABLE_1.EXECUTIVENAME = @Executivename

   UNION ALL

   SELECT ACCOUNTNO
        , -RECEIVEDAMOUNT AS DUE -- NOTE NEGATIVE SIGN
   FROM TABLE 3
   INNER JOIN TABLE_1 
   ON TABLE_1.ACCOUNTNO = TABLE3.ACCOUNTNO
   WHERE TABLE_1.EXECUTIVENAME = @Executivename
   ) SUB

GROUP BY SUB.ACC
```

Comment: thanks a lot bendataclear, by your help, I am able to get the results. But need help regarding the Daily and Monthly reports along with currentamount, anotheramount, receivedamount. Rest of the people, please help me in this regards..

Comment: If it's not related to this problem just post as a new question.